# Why is my project not saving a modification made in a name

Tags: c++

this is my first question on this site and also my first project.

I need to modify a name(surname/mail/etc) in it, but I've been stuck for almost two days.

The name is saved in a vector of an object called CLIENTS. 
I took the Client with a function, with another I try to modify it but nothing happens...

Here are the parts of the code.

**Financial.h**

```
    Cliente &SelectClient(int i); //To take a Client for further modification

private:
    std::vector<Cliente> m_clientes;
```

**Financial.cpp**

```
Cliente &Financiero::SelectClient(int i){
    return m_clients[i];
}
```

**Client.h**

```
    void EditName(std::string);
```

**Client.cpp**

```
void Cliente::EditName(std::string nom){
    this->m_nom = nom; //Here I replace the original name
}
```

And then, trying to make it work:

```
        int quien_mod; //Who is going to be modified
        cin >> quien_mod;
        quien_mod -= 1; //For making a counter from 0
        Cliente Cliente_a_Mod = Negocio.SelectClient(quien_mod); //Make a new client equal to the one tryied to edit
        int que_mod; //What I want to modify
        cin >> que_mod;

        string editing;
        switch(que_mod){
            case 1:
            {
                cin.ignore();
                cout << "New name: ";
                getline(cin,editing);
                Cliente_a_Mod.EditName(editing);

                break;
            }
```

Tryed to make it as simple as I could.

Thank you!

Comment: `Cliente& Cliente_a_Mod = Negocio.SelectClient(quien_mod);` Note the ampersand. Without it, you are making a copy of the vector element, and modifying that copy; the original element is never updated.

Comment: You should be able to do `void EditName(const std::string&);` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I finally made an ampersand to the Client so when I modify it, I edit also the original one, and added a line:

```
Cliente &Cliente_a_Mod = Negocio.SelectClient(quien_mod);

Cliente_a_Mod.EditarNombre(editando);
**Negocio.SaveClients();** //Added this line for saving in my binary file the modifications.
```

Thank you both!